# Allow Django user to create another one

Tags: python, django, django-models

first of all, I'm a beginner.

I'm creating a website for my family to trade presents on Christmas. Everyone can post gifts ideas for everyone.

I'd like to allow parents to create an account for their children and be able to manage them. E.g. rename, delete, change profile picture...

I have a profile model linked to User...

I was thinking of creating a child model...? But I'm stuck.

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far!

Comment: @StefGou Here is a good blog post from Vitor Freitas that covers what you are trying to accomplish https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/01/18/how-to-implement-multiple-user-types-with-django.html If you are a beginner and wanting to learn Django, this site is highly recommended!

Comment: You can add your code for the better understanding of the problem. You can add two signup forms for children and parents, link child model with parents and give permission to the linked parent to edit or rename etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think a posiblity could be make a model with one to one relationship to user class, as the documentation says:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model

and in that model put the custom data you want to be editable, and a privileged role may edit the unprivileged ones

I am leaving an example I've used :

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models

class Profile(models.Model):
    """Profile model

    Proxi model that extends de base data
    with orher information
    """
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    website = models.URLField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    biography = models.TextField(blank=True)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)

    picture = models.ImageField(
        upload_to="users/pictures",
        blank=True,
        null=True)

    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

I hope it could be usefull to you

Comment: and after that you could edit the admin site in order to add or edit new users